# How do you use cascading parameters in Report Builder 2.0 with a dynamic parameter value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm trying to build a report in Report Builder 2.0 that grabs some data from a query, and based on the results returned from that query, uses it as a parameter for a second query that returns a different set of data.

I have it setup so that the result (displayed in a table) of the first query is passed as a parameter to the second query. The problem is that only one value can be passed as the parameter. My intention was to pass **EACH** of the available values from the first result, and fill a table based on the results of each parameter. Is this possible?

NOTE: The structure of the database tables prevents writing a query to handle both actions in one query. Two queries is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Reporting Builder 3.0, I'm not sure if this solution applies to Report Builder 2.0.

You can pass a list of values to a parameter.  In your query for the second parameter, instead of writing

```
WHERE column ='@FirstParameterName
```

write

```
WHERE column IN (@FirstParameterName)
```

Hope that helps.

Patrick